# ASP.NET MVC HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

i keep get this error when the path is already exists in the web server i can't find any solution [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVlXG.png)

i tried to make a button so the user can have access to the edit action of another controller but this is happened , the edit action is working all good and already exisits

Comment: Please share the code...